# .NET IOC container that allows removal of registrations

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control

I'm only really familiar with AutoFac, and I asked if the feature detailed below was possible with it, and it seemed 'not exactly'. Do you know a container with which this would be possible?

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeCunningTests
{
    class SomeType        {        }

    [Test]
    public void TestRegistrationScope()
    {
        var container = new IocContainerOfSomeKind();
        using (new RegistrationScope(container, new SomeType()))
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(container.IsRegistered(typeof(SomeType)));
        }
        Assert.IsFalse(container.IsRegistered(typeof(SomeType)));
    }

    public class RegistrationScope<T> : IDisposable
    {
        public RegistrationScope(IocContainerOfSomeKind container, T instance)
        {
            //code here for registering instance
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            //unregister instance somehow
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com) would work with this scenario.  I believe all you'd need to do is use an AggregateCatalog for your catalog, which provides the ability to add to and remove from your catalog at runtime, since it exposes a [ComposablePartCatalogCollection](http://mef.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/30766#455548).

The catalog is basically the registry of types that's used for composition.